# Django autocomplete from query db

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I have problem with autocomplete an input field from db query. If I write something in the input field nothing happens. I didn't receive any errors from django prompt or browser console futhermore if I go to for example 127.0.0.0.1:8000/guess_booknames/?q=San it return back a page with JSON content so the "def guess_booknames" works good. Maybe it's wrong the query.html?

models.py:

```
class EbooksDBProfile(models.Model):

    bookname = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=False)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^guess_booknames/$', guess_booknames,name='autocomplete book names'),
```

views.py:

```
def guess_booknames(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET.get('q','')
        ebook_list_bookname=[]
        ebook_dict={}
        ebook_object=EbooksDBProfile.objects.all().filter(bookname__icontains=query)
        for p in ebook_object:
            ebook_list_bookname.append(p.bookname)

        ebook_dict['options']=ebook_list_bookname
        data=json.dumps(ebook_dict)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
    return HttpResponse()
```

query.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

  <input type="search" name="searched_item" id="searched_item" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter book name (eg. Head First Java)" style="max-width: 700px;width: 700px;color: threeddarkshadow;">

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#searched_item').typeahead({
      items:12,
        source: function (query, process) {
              return $.get('/guess_booknames/', { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data.options);
              });
            },
            minLength:3,
            autoSelect:false,

  highlighter: function (item) {
      var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
      return item.replace( regex, "<strong style='color:green;' >$1</strong>" );
  },
  });
  })
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using incorrect parameter name.  In your javascript part, you are using `query` while in your view, you are using just `q`.

```
# { query: query } should just be { q: query }
return $.get('/guess_booknames/', { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data.options);
              });
```

**Update:**
I think you are using the wrong version of typeahead, if it is alright with you, you can use the latest version.  I get it to work in this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

    <input type="text" name="searched_item" id="searched_item"  placeholder="Enter book name (eg. Head First Java)" style="max-width: 700px;width: 700px;color: threeddarkshadow;">

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#searched_item').typeahead({
                minLength:3,
                highlight: true
            },
            {
                name: 'books',
                source: function (query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
                    $.get('/guess_booknames/', { q: query }, function (data) {
                        asyncResults(data.options);
                    });
                },
                autoSelect:false,
                highlighter: function (item) {
                    var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
                    return item.replace( regex, "<strong style='color:green;' >$1</strong>" );
                }
            });
       });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Take note that the `<script src` for typeahead is different and I have changed some part of your javascript.

Comment: hmmm, did you get a `200` response from the server? you may want to log what is the value of data, something like `console.log(data);` and check it in the browser console.

Comment: yes 200 response. I'm newbie with jquery where I need to put console.log(data);?

Comment: You can put it before the `return process(data.options);` line and then using chrome browser, right click on your page and then click inspect, then go to the Console tab.

Comment: Done, no message display in the console also if I write in the input field

Comment: @lausent I have updated my answer and see if it works.

Comment: now it works, thanks. minLength:3 needs to be before "highlight: true" or doesn't work

Comment: @lausent Updated it, please mark it as answer if you can. Thanks! :)

Comment: how can I mark it as answer?

P.S. is there a way to display "no result" when a user type but the query is empy (no match)?

Comment: @lausent you can click the up arrow in my answer above.  For "no result", you can add a condition in your view before the json.dumps `if len(ebook_list_bookname) == 0: ebook_list_bookname.append('No result')`

Comment: I mark as answer and click useful answer. Thanks for you help, actually I think a need more information about Jquery function because I can understand only a part of code. I insert also 'no resunt', anyway the graphic field isn't really beauty bacause doesn't appear something like datepicker...the background is trasparent.